# How to make Http Post request using CefSharp

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I have a WPF application where I use CefSharp Browser control to render web pages. I need to be able to perform an HttpPost and open the uri. I looked through CefSharp documentation and haven't found any concrete examples to achieve this functionality but I'm sure this may be a feature that is part of the CefSharp component. Any pointers to how to achieve this would be quite helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a Url back from your Http Post or some HtmlContent ?

The HttpPost either way has nothing to do with the Web Browser Control.

You can make an Http Post outside of the control, which in turn would return you the html content, and you would use CefSharp to display the content returned using the **LoadHtml** function, or if you are getting a Url back from your post, then you just need to set the Url of your webbrowser wpf control to the Url returned by your Http Post.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understood that this is the way it works after posting the question here and you confirmed it. Thanks again!